# Change the position of (help) popup. Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, popup

```
<a href="#" id="example" data-toggle="tooltip" title="This will help you differentiate your workouts." style="float:right">
            <img src="../../img/help_icon.png" style="float:right;height:25px;"/>
        </a>
        <!-- Generated markup by the plugin -->
        <div class="tooltip top" role="tooltip">
          <div class="tooltip-arrow"></div>
          <div class="tooltip-inner">Test</div>
        </div>
```

This is my HTML Code. Used Bootstrap tooltip. This code has 3 div classes. When the mouse rolls over the image the pop-up was displayed but not at the right place. Its appearing Somewhere in the top. I have tried to change the position but the corresponding div class, "tooltip fade top in" is appearing only when the mouse is rolling on the image and it will disappear as I move the mouse. The class name is "tooltip fade top in".][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grvmq.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#" id="example" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-placement="top" title="This will help you differentiate your workouts." style="float:right">
        <img src="../../img/help_icon.png" style="float:right;height:25px;"/>
    </a>
```